# How to pull and deploy a docker image from azure container registry using Terraform?

Tags: azure, docker, terraform, azure-container-registry

I am new to using Terraform/Azure and I have been trying to work on a automation job since few days, which has wasted a lot of my time as I couldn't find any solutions on internet for the same.
So, if anyone knows how to pull and deploy a docker image from an azure container registry using Terraform then please do share the details for the same, any assistance will be most appreciated.
A sample code snippet word be of great assistance.

Comment: Where do you want to deploy the image?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [docker provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/index.html) and [docker_image resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/r/image.html) from terraform which pulls the image to your local docker registry. There are some [Authentication options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication#service-principal) to authenticate to ACR.

```html
provider "docker" {
    host = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

    registry_auth {
        address = "<ACR_NAME>.azurecr.io"
        username = "<DOCKER_USERNAME>"
        password = "<DOCKER_PASSWORD>"
    }
}

resource "docker_image" "my_image" {
    name = "<ACR_NAME>.azurecr.io/<IMAGE>:<TAG>"
}

output "image_id" {
    value = docker_image.my_image.name
}
```

Then use the image to deploy it with [docker_container resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/r/container.html). I have not used this resource so I cannot give you a snippet, but there are some examples on the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

One option to pull (and run) an image from ACR with Terraform is using Container Instances. Simple example for image reference:

```
resource "azurerm_container_group" "example" {
 name                = "my-continst"
 location            = "location"
 resource_group_name = "name"
 ip_address_type     = "public"
 dns_name_label      = "aci-uniquename"
 os_type             = "Linux"

 container {
  name   = "hello-world"
  image  = "acr-name.azurecr.io/aci-helloworld:v1"
  cpu    = "0.5"                                                                                                                                                               
  memory = "1.5"

  ports {        
   port     = 80
   protocol = "TCP"
  }
 }

 image_registry_credential {
  server = "acr-name.azurecr.io" 
  username = ""    
  password = ""
  }
}
```